# How to sync 2 id columns (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql

I am writing a MySQL Database (database in general) for the first time, and I cannot figure how to sync a foreign id column with my current table's id column. This table holds the description for the data, the other table is just a log with a id, and time stamp. How do I make the id columns sync?

Comment: if the log just parallels the main table, why have a seperate auto_increment at all? insert into the main table, get insert_id(), use that to insert into log table.

Comment: It sounds like the foreign key set up didn't include any constrains.  You can set the foreign key to cascade on update so it will stay correct if the ID changes.  I'm not entirely sure it's what you mean, but have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html